# Android app removed due to BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN, that is not present in the manifest

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

I'm having a really strange problem with an app in the Play Store.

My code is unique and produces about 20 app for the same number of clients which have some little customization.

Only for one of these clients, Google removed the app from the play store due to "DEVICE ADMIN ABUSE​", and this is the specific message:

> We don’t allow app that provide inaccurate disclosure of there functionality and do not perform as expected by user. Also developer must explain to users why you are requesting the 'android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN' in their app.

The problem is that our app does not use that permission!
So I have appealed and my appeal was accepted: Google told me to re-submit the app using the same APK, but it was rejected for the same reason!!

Anyone had this problem? Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Check your libraries.  Permissions are transitive, if one of your dependencies use it, or even declare it, so will your app.  Be especially careful of any advertising libraries (which tend to be scummy) and any libraries that aren't major open source ones (if you're using some random library found on github, don't be surprised when it suddenly becomes malware).

Comment: Thanks Gabe, but in that case I think that permission will show up in the manifest of the generated apk or in the build details on the play store page, right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: It should show up in the generated APK.  I would trust that more than the store listing, which isn't necessarily 1:1 with permissions.  Although it may be they're requesting it as a runtime permission?  That wouldn't be caught by the generated apk, although I don't think it would work without putting it in the manifest as well.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for your reply, but as you can see from my own answer, the app was good... something happened on the google review procedure

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question for anyone who had/has/will have the same problem...

After a second appeal, the Google Team told me to deactivate the "App bundle version code 1" and re-send a new one with incremented version.

The strange thing is that the previously published version cose was 7, and not 1... The only one place wherea "version code 1" could be found was in the test section, bundle that was not evend sent for a review...

Anyway we deleted that "version code 1" and sent a new buondle with incremented version code.... and it was finally accepted...

So... yes... there was definitely a problem on the Google revision procedure...